# Console as desktop background in Windows 10 / Server 2016

Tags: windows-10, command-line, desktop-customization, windows-server-2016

I want to replace the default image/slideshow desktop background with a usable console (cmd, powershell, whatever). This console should behave the same as a normal desktop background, i.e. it should not be accessible via Alt+Tab, only via Win+D, and it should always stay behind the taskbar and any other windows.

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, I have been using this for very very long time.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

Comment: Please add an explanation as to how you can set the console to replace the Windows desktop wallpaper.